# What is this grammatical rule that applies here?

Tags: grammar

So I was doing an elementary level of English language test, and I stumbled upon the following question.

> Go past the library, and bus station is opposite _____ the cathedral.

Available answers to this are: a) of b) - (blank) c) from d) to

I answered d) but the woman checking the test said it was supposed to be b) or in other words left blank.

Why is that and whats the rule behind it?

Comment: There seems to be a word missing before the blank.  None of the answers make sense,

Comment: The only difference I allowed myself to make is changing "us station" (taken from the source) to "bus station" as I believe it is print mistake.

Comment: Omg, I am so sorry, I missed it

Comment: *the bus station? If so, blank is right.

Comment: No, there was no "the" in front of bus station, but why it should be blank, can you explain?

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/opposite-or-in-front-of

Comment: https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/250077-quot-Opposite-of-something-quot-or-quot-opposite-something-quot

Comment: As written it's invalid, for US English.  There should be an article in front of "bus station".  As to the answer, blank or "from" would be idiomatic, while "to" is acceptable.

Comment: @HotLicks 'The' is needed before 'bus station' in UK English too, but I would answer '(blank) or to'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the word `opposite` is being used as a preposition and requires no additional preposition. If you said,

> The bus station is **on** the *opposite side of* the cathedral

you are now using the word `opposite` as an adjective. In this usage, the preposition `of` is appropriate to use with the noun `side`.